# when using from selenium import webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium, import, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am very new to Python, and I am stuck. I searched for hours for a solution but I could not figure it out.

It was working perfectly but it stoped suddenly. I have both Selenium and Webdriver installed.

I am simply trying to:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

and I am getting that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 19, in <module>
    import http.client as http_client
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/Users/MacMaison/Documents/email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 21, in <module>
    import httplib as http_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'httplib'
```

I am using:
MacOS Sierra
Python 3.6.2

Here is part of the code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "/Users/MacMaison/Downloads/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

it stops in the second line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it, after 10 hours searching.
The problem was that `I had created a file named email.py`, I just had to rename this file, 
A rookie mistake, 
I hope it can be useful to someone.

Comment: Thanks @heisenberg, it solved my problem and I guess I just saved 10 hours!